# Running multiple Jetty server in a single jUnit test

Tags: java, rest, maven, junit, jetty

I am trying to start multiple jetty servers(each on different port) in a jUnit test and test the same rest endpoint for each of those jetty servers.

I am able to start them successfully, however whenever I query the endpoint on any of the servers, the request is always received by a single jetty server regardless of which port I sent the request to.

I have confirmed that the jetty servers are all started on different ports and there is a service listening on each of those ports. Just the request is always received on the same port regardless of which port it's actually sent to.

Is it not possible to start multiple jetty servers on different ports serving the same path?
Has anyone been able to do this before?

Code :

```java
    // Starting the jettyServer
    jettyServer = new Server();
    handlerCollection = new HandlerCollection(true);
    ServerConnector serverConnector = new ServerConnector(jettyServer);

    // The port is passed in to this class. Verified that this is being done correctly.
    serverConnector.setPort(this.port);
    jettyServer.setConnectors(new ServerConnector[] { serverConnector });
    jettyServer.setHandler(handlerCollection);
    jettyServer.start();

    // Config has been configured correctly for the application, verified that
    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler();
    context.setContextPath(conf.getString("pathForRestContext"));
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig();
    config.packages(conf.getString("packageForRest"));
    ServletHolder servletHolder = new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer(config));
    context.addServlet(servletHolder, "/*");

    // Append our handler to any existing handlers
    handlerCollection.addHandler(newHandler);
    try {
        newHandler.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Error starting new handler: ", e);
        throw e;
    }

    // Sending the request
    URI uri = new URIBuilder()
        .setScheme(httpProtocol)
        .setHost(server.getHostName())
        .setPort(portForJetty)
        .setPath(restEndpoint)
        .build();

    // Using the same httpclient for all of the requests, however using individual clients does not solve the problem.
    Response response = httpClient.target(uri).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get();

    // responseType is a custom class which is the expected data type for the incoming data.
    response.readEntity(responseType)
```

Comment: Yes this is possible, and the Jetty source itself does this regularly to test it's own proxy implementations (*test client -> test server that acts as proxy -> proxy client -> test server that acts as endpoint for request*).    Perhaps if you provide some code showing what you are doing then it could help us formulate a direct answer for you.

Comment: Added relevant code sections as an edit to the question itself. Thanks @JoakimErdfelt

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt any chance you were able to look at the code?